# How to handle the drag & drop of a hyperlink in GWT

Tags: gwt, hyperlink, drag-and-drop

I want to handle the drag & drop of hyperlinks in my app. The hyperlink could be from any where,  therefore I cannot make it `setDragable(true)` and `setData("link", "the URL")` to mark it.

A very similar scenario would be Google Image search by image, where you can drag & drop a link of image to the search box.

The sample code,

```
Label lblDropLink = new Label("Drop a link here");
lblDropLink.addDragOverHandler(new DragOverHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onDragOver(DragOverEvent event) {
        lblDropLink.setText("Drop here to add the link.");
        lblDropLink.setStyleName("dragOverFade");
    }
});
lblDropLink.addDropHandler(new DropHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // QUESTION: how to get the link, and even its text?
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing you can get when dropping a link is the URL!

You can get it by calling the `event.getData(format)` method.

`format` can either be "text" or "url" (see [dom-datatransfer-getdata](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dnd.html#dom-datatransfer-getdata)). When testing it "text" and "url" always deliverd the same result.

So the code you need in "// QUESTION: how to get the link, and even its text?" is one of the two

- event.getData("text")
- event.getData("url")

Here is a little sample prgramm:

```
    final Label lblDropLink = new Label(defaultText);
    lblDropLink.addDragOverHandler(new DragOverHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onDragOver(DragOverEvent event) {
            lblDropLink.setText(dragOverText);
        }
    });

    lblDropLink.addDropHandler(new DropHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            RootPanel.get().add(new Label("Dropped source formated with \"text\": " + event.getData("text")));
            RootPanel.get().add(new Label("Dropped source formated with \"url\":  " + event.getData("url")));
        }
    });

    RootPanel.get().add(lblDropLink);
}
```

That should be all...

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. This works for getting the URL. However event.getData("text") also returns the URL rather than the text. Any way to change that?

Comment: Sorry, can't find out why, but had the same problem. As I see it, when draging a link, only the url is in the drag information.... Also I couldn't find what other fields my be defined in for format (the format basically points to a key value pair...=

Comment: I think that's how the standard is implemented. Maybe later the mainstream browsers would support properly both the __text__ and __url__. You answer is good enough for now, thanks again @Stefan.

Comment: thank you :). glad I could help. An 1.000 points now. Yeahhhhh^^

Answer (score 0):

There is a function called `getSource()`. Use it to cast the source of the dragged object and get the link property of the source object in the onDrop event.

Example:

```
 public void onDrop(DropEvent event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     Link link = (Link)event.getSource(); 
 }
```

Link is the object being dragged. Then you can call `Link.getLink()` or whatever you use to get the value of the link.

Hpope you get the concept :)

Comment: Not true. If you try to debug event.getSource() you would see it's actual the Label object, rather than "Link".